# Adding "UOM" (Unit of Measure) in field - OpenErp

Tags: python, module, field, odoo, inheritance

I need to add A unit of measure field in module, this is my code

```
    _columns = {
            'Items' : fields.integer('Items'),
            'Codigo Arancelario' : fields.integer('Codigo Arancelario'),
            'Descripcion Arancelaria' : fields.char('Descripcion Arancelaria', size=42, required = True, translate = True), 
            'Especificaciones Tecnicas' : fields.char('Especificaciones Tecnicas', size=60, required = True, translate = True), 
            'Cantidad' : fields.float('Cantidad'),
            'Precio Unitario Declarado' : fields.float('Precio Unitario Declarado'),
            'Valor En Divisas' : fields.float('Valor En Divisas'),
            'notas' : fields.text('Notas'),
            }
```

In the 'Cantidad' field i need to add a UOM field.

Should i inherit this by 'self.pool.get(object)'?

For example 'Cantidad' (Quantity) should be expressed in tons, so that's why i need the UOM field.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add many2one field to 'product.uom'

```
'uom_id': fields.many2one('product.uom', 'Uom')
```